# How to safely secure micro-services in AWS VPC with ALB and OAuth server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, oauth, amazon-vpc, aws-ecs

**tldr: See bold generic questions below.**

I have built the infrastructure outlined below(in attachment) in AWS. OAuth specifies an auth server which issues tokens(Authorizes) and then authenticates tokens on each request and allows a proxy to the internal ALB.

It's based on a micro-services architecture and uses oauth to issue tokens and authenticate them from the client apps. The client apps could be apps inside the VPC or apps external to the VPC. As you can see I want all requests to go through OAuth server before they get to the internal ALB. Now the different types of apps should use different types of grants to get an access tokens. Those access tokens will contain a scope which relates to the routes(API endpoints) of the internal ALB.

Now I have a few questions which I hope are as succinct as possible:

### AWS VPC ALB Questions

1. **What is the most secure way of insuring that only the oauth apps communicate with the internal ALB and not other apps in the public subnet?** So we can be sure that all requests to the internal ALB are authenticated? Do I have to somehow attach a new oauth only subnet to the input of internal ALB but how do I restrict the internal ALBs input?
2. **To the same end, how do I ensure apps in the same subnet do not communicate with each other?** Basically, how do I ensure that no internal apps communicate with each other and must be passed all the way to the external load balancer and therefore to oauth from the private subnet.

### Route 53 SLL termination ALB

**Does SSL termination on certain port stop traffic directed from different domains.** If I make a call to ALB port 433 from internal ALB with SSL termination do I have to call from the host(route53 something.com) specified by the certificate or can I use the DNS hostname of the ALB(something.elb.amozonaws.com) resolved by AWS ok?

### Scopes and OAuth

**How to compare each request's url and it's token with oauth scopes?** I want to relate oauth scopes to api endpoints. So each request goes to a route endpoint with an access_token which contains scopes. This scope will have to be compared with the request url on each request to make sure it’s allowed. Does oauth come with this functionality? I would guess not. However whats the point of scopes if this is not the case? Seems like scope is just an array I need to do some processing on after authentication rather than it being special in oauth. I’m probably missing something :-).

This post is too long already so I can’t for obvious reasons get into all the details but if you would like more detail I would of course give them. Even a help in the right direction would be useful at this point.

Thanks in advance.

[image: The overview of infrastructure]